# Using Youtube with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

I have been have been having problems getting fancybox to function so that youtube videos will display in a lightbox fashion.

Instead they go directly to a full screen view of the youtube video, which I believe means that fancybox js crashed.

Maybe this is due to the other js in use on the page, but i have looked through several help sites and found nothing - I hope you can help?

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

            <!----Fancybox--->
            <!-- Add jQuery library -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

            <!-- Add fancyBox -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

            <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

            <!---Cookie Bar--->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.cookiebar.css" />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookiebar.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(document).ready(function(){
                            $.cookieBar({
                                declineButton: true,

                            });
                        });
            });
            if(jQuery.cookieBar('cookies')){


             cookie content here

            }
            </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <!---Desktop/tablet display links as responsive image maps--->    
            <div class="hotspot">
            <img name="animations" src="images/bigpic1.jpg" width="1280" height="878" id="animations" usemap="#m_animations" alt="" /><map name="m_animations" id="m_animations">
            <area shape="poly" coords="620,598,1018,598,736,0,702,1,518,387,719,387,620,598" class="fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/genericlinkhere.html" title="my title" alt="my alt tag" />
            </map>
            </div>

        <!---Mobile display links--->
            <div class="mob_gal">
            <a class="fancybox.iframe" href=www.youtube.com/embed/genericlinkhere.html title="my title" alt="my alt tag"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
            </div>

            <!---Mobile Navigation--->
            <script src="js/mini_nav.js"></script>
            <script src="js/doubletaptogo.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( function()
                {
                    $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
                });
            </script>

            <!---Responsive Image Maps--->
            <script src="js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();


            });
            </script>

            <!---Fancybox Opener--->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    maxWidth    : 800,
                    maxHeight   : 600,
                    fitToView   : false,
                    width       : '70%',
                    height      : '70%',
                    autoSize    : false,
                    closeClick  : false,
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none'
                });
            });
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the selector `.fancybox` to fancybox like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

... so you have to set the class `fancybox` in your anchor **apart** from the special class `fancybox.iframe` like :

```
<div class="mob_gal">
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/genericlinkhere" title="my title" alt="my alt tag"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
</div>
```

**Notice** the space between `fancybox` and `fancybox.iframe` inside the *class* attribute

Also **notice** the `href` syntax `href="..."` (you were missing the quotes around the link)

See <kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NhVKS/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi JFK, I have done what you suggested, but it hasn't helped I'm afraid.. Could I perhaps pm the official page I am working on for you to see the issue up close?

Comment: Hi, Further to your answer, I have individually switched off each of the other jquery's and discovered that the mobile navigation was to blame! Thanks for your help. :)